# Python LinkedList size/delete functions aren't working

Tags: python

This is my node:

```
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, data, next = None):
      self.data = data
      self.next_node = next

    def get_next(self):
      return self.next_node

    def set_next(self, next):
      self.next_node = next

    def get_data(self):
      return self.data

    def set_data(self):
      self.data = data
```

And this is the LinkedList itself:

```
class LinkedList(object):
    def __init__(self, root = None):
      self.root = root
      self.size = 0

    def size(self):
      return self.size

    def insert(self, data):
      new_node = Node (data, self.root)
      self.root = new_node
      self.size += 1

    def delete(self, data):
      this_node = self.root
      prev_node = None
      while this_node:
        if this_node.get_data() == data:
          if prev_node:
            prev_node.set_next(this_node.get_next())
          else:
            self.root = this_node
          self.size -= 1
          return True
        else:
          prev_node = this_node
          this_node = this_node.get_next()
      return False

    def search(self, data):
      this_node = self.root
      while this_node:
        if this_node.get_data() == data:
          return data
        else:
          self.root = this_node.get_next()
        return None

    def printLL(self):
      this_node = self.root
      while this_node:
        print(this_node.data)
        this_node  = this_node.get_next()
```

Finally, these are the tests I'm performing:

```
ll = LinkedList()
ll.insert(1)
ll.insert(2)
ll.printLL()
ll.delete(2)
ll.printLL()
if ll.search(2):
    print("Value 2 found")
else:
    print("Value 2 not found")
if ll.search(1):
    print("Value 1 found")
else:
    print("Value 1 not found")
ll.insert(4)
ll.printLL()
print(str(ll.size()))
```

I am currently getting this output:

```
2
1
2
1
Value 2 found
Value 1 not found
4
1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ErikIngvoldsen\Documents\Python Code\TestCode.py", line 71, in <module>
    print(str(ll.size()))
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

Why is the object not callable? Also, why isn't my delete function working? For reference, this is what my output SHOULD look like:

```
2 1
1
Value 2 not found
Value 1 found
4 1
2
```

There's also the formatting problem, but for now I'll just focus on getting this to work properly.

Answer (score 0):

size is a instance variable not a method of the linkedlist class. You cannot call a variable.That is the error. instead of doing `print(str(ll.size()))`, do `print(str(ll.size))`

Comment: What's the difference exactly? Is there a way for this to work while calling print(str(ll.size()))?

Comment: you cannot call a variable. when ever you are using "()", it means that you are expecting to execute a function. Just take basic Python tutorials on functions, i think you will understand it properly.